# TYPO3 system extension "install" overwrite with my own class

Tags: typo3, extbase

I would like to override a method of TYPO3 system extension "instal" -> Class **TYPO3\CMS\Install\SystemEnvironment\Check** with my own class **VENDOR\Examples\Xclass\Backend\Check** but it's not working.

Other classes in the system extesion for example as **TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Controller\LoginController** or **TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Template\DocumentTemplate** can I without problems with the help of XLASS overwrite.

It is generally possible to overwrite the install tools classes from own extension?

```
<?php

defined('TYPO3_MODE') || die('Access denied.');

if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {

    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['TYPO3\\CMS\\Install\\SystemEnvironment\\Check'] = array(
        'className' => 'ALEX\\Examples\\Xclass\\Backend\\Check'
    );

    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['TYPO3\\CMS\\Backend\\Controller\\LoginController'] = array(
        'className' => 'ALEX\\Examples\\Xclass\\Backend\\LoginController'
    );

    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['TYPO3\\CMS\\Backend\\Template\\DocumentTemplate'] = array(
        'className' => 'ALEX\\Examples\\Xclass\\Backend\\DocumentTemplate'
    );
}
```

Comment: Not 100% sure if it works out but you can copy the install extension, change the composer package name in your clone, and add an replace key.

```
"replace": {
    "typo3/cms-install":"self.version"
}
```

This way you can at least customize the extension as you desire.

Comment: I tried but it's not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible as the class is not called via `GeneralUtility::makeInstance`. Furthermore it is also stated in the class:

> @internal This class is only meant to be used within EXT:install and
>   is not part of the TYPO3 Core API.

If you are missing a feature or think you got a bug you should open an issue at https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/issues